# Python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 at pip install psycopg2

Tags: php, psycopg2

```
[root@Nav15 nav15]# pip install psycopg2
Collecting psycopg2
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Using cached psycopg2-2.6.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
    /tmp/pip-build-Fh_XN3/psycopg2/setup.py:12: DeprecationWarning: Parameters to load are deprecated.  Call .resolve and .require separately.
      # FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU Lesser General Public
    writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found
    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
    or specify the full executable path with the option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Fh_XN3/psycopg2
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: install pip install psycopg2 in centros

Comment: error-Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-vg2MKH/psycopg2